# Why are no diagnostics required for missing definitions?

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer

Consider the following sentence in the C++ standard:

> Every program shall contain at least one definition of every function or variable that is [odr-used](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#def:odr-use) in that program outside of a *[discarded statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#def:discarded_statement)*; no diagnostic required. [...]

- [[basic.def.odr] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#11.sentence-1)

My intuition is that if a function or variable is odr-used, and no definitions exists anywhere, this results in a linker error in practice. It should be relatively easy for a compiler and linker to detect.

Is there ever a case where missing definitions in a program are too hard to diagnose, justifying this being IFNDR?

Comment: Not that the standard cares or acknowledges them, but shared libraries would be a pain to work with if this was diagnosable.

Comment: The standard doesn't really say much about linking, requiring a diagnostic here would restrict the possible usages of the language

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica if the dynamic library is loaded with run-time loading, then there aren't really any missing function calls that would need to be diagnosed, only system calls. If the library was loaded at load-time of the program, it should still be easy to diagnose that the DLL is missing function calls which the program expects. Is this not done in practice, and simple to do anyway?

Comment: What about optimizations removing the use? [`extern int i; int main() { i; }`](https://godbolt.org/z/53n47osMr)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer blanket-removing uses of entities when the compiler doesn't know anything about what they do would be a violation of the as-if rule, and a gross violation of developer intent. The optimization there makes sense though, and is a fair point. I guess this lets the compiler optimize out any pointless uses of symbols without informing the linker that they should be used anyway.

Comment: The linker can detect that there is a missing definition.  The **compiler** cannot detect this kind of problem, because the **compiler** would have to have holistic knowledge of all *translation units*.  Which it does not, it only has limited knowledge of only the particular translation unit it is compiling.  (Hence the value of tools like Coverity that do holistic static analysis, which the compiler cannot do with it's lint-like *not required by the standard* warnings.)

Comment: @Eljay the C++ standard makes demands towards the *implementation* though, which includes the compiler and the linker. [Phase 9 of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) is linking, so linking isn't out of the scope of the standard in general.

Comment: And also includes the runtime, since the definitions might be dynamically loaded at runtime.  And possibly un-loaded and re-loaded at runtime — a technique that one of my co-workers uses when working on code so he can make live C++ code changes with very rapid turnaround.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer `i;` is not an odr-use of `i` though, is it? https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5.3

Comment: Every header file provides a declaration fore tones of functions. A diagnostic for missing definitions of an include file would just confuse the progrmmer, if the function was never used. In addition some useful metaprogramming constructs(`std::declval`) would never be available otherwise.

Comment: @user17732522 can replace with `&i;`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica "_but shared libraries would be a pain to work with if this was diagnosable_" Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AlanBirtles "_requiring a diagnostic here would restrict the possible usages of the language_" Do you know of any real case of such "restriction"?

Comment: @curiousguy see the answer, it has 2 examples

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't see a real world example or even the hint of a useful construct that uses undefined functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there ever a case where missing definitions in a program are too hard to diagnose, justifying this being IFNDR?

If a diagnostic was required, then the compiler would e.g. be forced to emit some reference to a function, even if the compiler knows that the call can never actually happen in order for the linker to detect and diagnose the missing definition.

For example:

```
void f();

int main() { if(false) f(); }
```

`f()` is odr-using `f`, but it is guaranteed to never be called which compiler optimizations can easily detect. So the compiler shouldn't have to emit a reference to `f` just to provide an unnecessary diagnostic.

Depending on how you see dynamic libraries fitting into the standard's context, it would also make it impossible for them stay conforming, because dynamic linking typically doesn't require diagnosing missing definitions until load time or until a call actually happens.

Comment: I don't think the DLL issue amounts to much, because either you load them at run-time, in which case you're just calling `LoadLibrary` and other system functions, and those aren't missing, or alternatively, load-time DLL loading could check whether the functions you need are all in the shared library. Either way, this is diagnosable without too much effort.

Comment: @JanSchultke Even dynamic linking at the start of program execution can typically be configured to delay linking until a symbol is actually required. At least that mode would still be non-conforming.

Comment: The argument with having to diagnose optimized-out function calls is genuine though. Still, it's not completely unreasonable to require diagnostics here, and might catch some bugs that are silently sitting in dead code sections, temporarily disabled by an `if (false)`.

Comment: Even if the actual linking is delayed, it should be easy to provide a system call which checks whether the expected symbols exist in a library, without necessarily finding all their addresses, or performing any other work.

Comment: @JanSchultke It is intentional though that there shouldn't be a diagnostic even if a symbol is missing as long as it isn't used during execution in that case. So that would then be a non-conforming configuration. But I agree it is not that significant.

Comment: I'm unconvinced on this explanation. The standard describes "phases of translation", not compilation and linking. The last (ninth) phase is (with identical wording in all C++ standards, AFAIK) "All external entity references are resolved. Library components are linked to satisfy external references to entities not defined in the current translation. All such translator output is collected into a program image which contains information needed for execution in its execution environment."  which can refer to either linking (in the "compile then link then run" sense) or loading DLLs at run time.

Comment: "_until a call actually happens_" Do you have an example of such linking system?

Comment: @curiousguy A usual gcc/glibc/binutils configuration with an ELF shared library compiled with `-Wl,-z,lazy`. It will fail at runtime only when you actually try to call a function that isn't defined in the loaded shared library.

Comment: Also `-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined` will suppress build time linker errors and both of these options are/were defaults at least under some OS according to the ld man page.